# Client sends message but not seen on server

Tags: c, sockets, sctp

I tried to create client-server in SCTP protocol using SCTP socket. It is my first time using sctp.

here is the client code

```
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 

int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, connfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

    // socket create and varification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // function for chat 
    char *buf="fuck this world";

    int l=sctp_sendmsg(sockfd, (void *) buf, strlen(buf) + 1, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    if(l>0)
        printf("send success\n");
    else printf("send failed\n");
    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
}
```

here is the server code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#define MAX 80 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 


// Driver function 
int main() 
{ 
    int sockfd, connfd, len; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 

    // socket create and verification 
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 

    // assign IP, PORT 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification 
    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) { 
        printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); 
    } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

    int buf[200];
    while(1)
    {
        int l=sctp_recvmsg(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),NULL,0,0,0);
        if(l>0)
            printf("%s\n",buf);
        sleep(1);
    }

    close(sockfd); 
}
```

the problem is the client is sending the message without any errors. but I do not see that message on the server. Maybe the server code is incorrect. why is it not working?
this code is only for learning. it I figure out how it works I will create client server to send files over sctp.

Comment: In the client, `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` should really be `sizeof servaddr`.

Comment: According to [the `sctp` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sctp.7.html), `SOCK_STREAM` sockets are *connected* (just like TCP) which means the server needs to not only `bind` the socket, but also `listen` to it and `accept` new connections. The client needs to `connect`. You can also use the plain `send` and `recv` functions to send and receive data.